# Parse iOS signUpInBackgroundWithBlock session not being created

Tags: ios, swift, session, parse-platform

Wondering if anyone knows possible reasons why a session would not be set on signup with signUpInBackgroundWithBlock() ? The user gets created without issue, but the session is never set (and doesn't get created in the data browser).

I have enableRevocableSessionInBackground() in the App delegate, and this isn't a migration. Tested resetting the simulator, still no luck. Logging in sets the session as expected.

Any ideas?

```
func processSignUp() {
    var userUsername = self.usernameField.text
    var userEmail = self.emailField.text.lowercaseString
    var userPassword = self.passwordField.text

    // Start activity indicator
    HUDController.sharedController.contentView = HUDContentView.ProgressView()
    HUDController.sharedController.show()

    // Create the user
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = userUsername
    user.password = userPassword
    user.email = userEmail

    // Sign up in background
    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {                
            HUDController.sharedController.hide()
            let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let tourViewController : TourViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Tour") as! TourViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tourViewController, animated: false)
        } else {
            HUDController.sharedController.hide()
            ErrorHandlingController.handleParseError(error!, viewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Here is some stripped code of the function where the sign up occurs - http://pastie.org/private/om1qldmibvtpyi8u0ibow

Comment: So the problem is that there is no record in the Parse database after you sign up like this?

Comment: Is this a legacy app?  Please present evidence that "the session is never set".

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the follow up. Done some further testing and the session IS set on sign up, but removed as soon as I call "saveInBackgroundWithBlock" on the current user. Seems like a very similar issue as here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/RMwM16BFcgI

Not a legacy app.